# Singleton UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to add some data from a random class to my viewController,

So to keep always the same data, i did a singleton on my UIViewController, but it doesnt work i never get the data on my tableview.

this what i added to my UIViewController :

```
+(id)sharedMBVC {
   static MBViewController *sharedMBVC ;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!sharedMBVC)
            sharedMBVC = [[MBViewController alloc] init];
        return sharedMBVC;
    }
}
```

and from my class i call it by doing this :

```
  MBViewController *vc = [MBViewController sharedMBVC];
```

Do i have to set somewhere the content of my NSArrays that they are declared in my viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller ? or there is something else to do.

PS : i was doing in my class before `vc =  (MBViewController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];` but now my uiviewcontroller its not a rootview anymore, thats why im trying to find other way to access to it, and i guess the best solution is to do a singleton

Can u help me guys

Comment: Don't do this. This is bad. What is it that you're doing that made you want to use a singleton? There **is** a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Fogmeister the main pb is that now im using AMSlideMenu, that his MainVC become a rootview, so now i dont have how to access to my MBViewController methods :s i want to have always the current MBViewController with his NSArrays updated

Comment: Why do you need access to the MBViewController from everywhere? Is it just to get the arrays?

Comment: to add the data to my arrays that i display later in the view.
 the pb the data i get them via other device with bluetooth so they are dynamic i need to remove and add everytime

Comment: OK, we're getting somewhere :) so, I guess that the "place" (view controller etc...) in the app that adds stuff to the arrays is far enough away to make it a pain to pass references around. Because of the menu controller?

Comment: yes before as i wrote in the post i was calling the rootview from the Appdelegate, but now my view its not a rootview anymore :( cuz the menuController get rootview place, i tried to add it in the viewControler that i need and like this i keep it as a root view, but doesnt work

Comment: OK, let me add an answer.

Comment: @fourthnovember, well, I think, these arrays don't belong to the VMBiewController from architectural point of view. I would separate them to a data layer (DataSource class of some sort, for instance) and keep a reference to the DataSource everywhere you need. Have a look at the [Second iOS App tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/SecondiOSAppTutorial.pdf) by Apple. It contains a simple example of data layer implementation.

Comment: @FreeNickname you read my mind, lol. Just adding an answer explaining this. lol

Comment: i already did a singleton in a class before it worked well, i dont understand why when i did same for my viewcontroller nothing happen it work but everytime i do reload view when i add data the view refresh and come back to the stats 0

Comment: viewController + singleton = this will break everything to do with how view controllers work. It's a bad idea to default back to singletons in the first place. Making a viewController a singleton, I don't even know what will be breaking because of that.

Comment: If you get to the MBViewController via a segue (which, I think, you are), then a new instance of MBViewController is created every time. If you access your arrays from MBViewController using `self.myArray`, then you access this new ViewController's myArray. While `sharedMBVC` keeps a reference to the shared instance, it's just ignored by the segue. I believe, it might be the reason.

Comment: @Fogmeister, we're thinking in sync :) I think, I will also make it an answer.

Comment: @FreeNickname there is a way to fix this? i tried to add - (id)init with the sharedMBVC and i putted the arrays there but same doesnt work :D

Comment: Well I could think of a couple of possible solutions, but these are all dirty hacks. Very, very ugly hacks. Since I don't want you to get [eaten by a raptor](http://xkcd.com/292/), I recomend you to follow our advice instead. Luckily, @fogmeister wrote a very fine answer about it :)

Comment: By the way, Welcome to SO :) I wouldn't usually write this, but since you're new here: upvotes and accepts are welcome :)

Comment: thank u how to follow ur adivce instead ? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the problem you have is that the viewController that displays the arrays also "owns" the arrays. This means that (with your current setup) to be able to change the arrays you need to get hold of the viewController to be able to access the arrays.

You need to change this by removing the arrays from that viewController.

You can still do this with a singleton (if you prefer) but create a brand new class called something like `ArrayManager`.

This will contain the arrays and ALL the methods for updating the arrays.

So for instance if your viewController has a method called `- (void)addObjectToArray:(id)object;` then move this method to the `ArrayManager` singleton class.

Now in your displaying viewController you can do...

```
[[ArrayManager sharedInstance] getSomeDataFromTheArray];
```

And in the place that has to update the array you can do...

```
[[ArrayManager sharedInstance] addObjectToArray:someObject];
```

Now you don't need to worry about passing the viewController around at all.

This can be improved with various things. For instance, you maybe don't need a singleton at all and can just take this `ArrayManager` class and **inject** it into the places that need it by setting a property etc...

Also, you could possibly use CoreData to store the information.

Also, your singleton method is not correct. The way recommended by Apple is to use...

```
+ (ArrayManager *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static ArrayManager *arrayManager;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        arrayManager = [[ArrayManager alloc] init];
    });
    return arrayManager;
}
```

**Rewriting your singleton...**

.h file

```
@interface PTVData : NSObject

+ (PTVData *)sharedInstance;

- (void)addSensor:(NSString *)sensorName;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSensors;
- (NSString *)sensorAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface PTVData ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sensors;

@end

@implementation PTVData

+ (PTVData)sharedInstance
{
    static PTVData *sharedPTVData;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPTVData  = [[PTVData alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedPTVData;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _sensors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:@"None"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addSensor:(NSString *)sensorName
{
    if (sensorName
        && ![self.sensors containsObject:sensorName]) {
        [self.sensors addObject:sensorName];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSensors
{
    return self.sensors.count;
}

- (NSString *)sensorAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return self.sensors[index];
}

@end
```

By doing this you hide the actual array of sensors. It is only directly accessible through the `PTVData` class.

Now in your tableview methods you can do...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[PTVData sharedInstance] numberOfSensors];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...

    cell.textLabel.text = [[PTVData sharedInstance] sensorAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i did it i got same pb the data doesnt display, in viewDidLoad i call my singleton class MyClass *myclass = [MyClass sharedInstance]; then _array1 = myclass.array1;

Comment: when i call the adddata in viewcontroller, the method call the adddata of Myclass, i put breakpoint all good it enter there but after when i come back to my viewcontroller i do array1=myclass.array1; again and then [self.tableview reloadData]; but he never do the reload i mean he dont call any tableview method :s, do u have any idea why i does this ?

Comment: @fourthnovember Can you stick some code onto gist or something. It's pretty much impossible to help without seeing the code.

Comment: @fourthnovember don't add an answer. Just edit your question.

Comment: opss i didnt saw ur comment :s check it plz and tell me what u think about it

Comment: @fourthnovember if you log the `self.sensorsCollection` in the `addSensor...` method does it show the added sensors? Next, in the displaying viewController don't store the `sensorsCollection` or `ptvdata` as properties. Just use `[PTVData sharedPTVData].sensorsCollection` to reference it. Don't pull the array out. Also, if you log out the array in the displaying viewController does the log show the correct values?

Comment: Also, are you using ARC or not?

Comment: Thank u i saw it, i will try it and let u know,during the day :)

Comment: @fourthnovember glad you got it working. Remember to up vote and accept if it helped you.

Comment: last question the data that i toke from my array, i use them in two uitableview the first it display good then second there is a margin top before the section title :s. u think i need to do a reloadData somewhere?

Comment: Is the gap about the same height as the navigation bar (64 points)? Have a look at automaticallyAdjustsScrollviewInsets. Either reposition the second table or set that property to NO;

Comment: +10 PB resloved thank you :) , but u think it gonna change nothing this if i will have lot of data or something ? i mean whats the meaning to have it the automaticallyAdjustsScrollviewInsets

Comment: In iOS7+ the content is visible behind the navigation controller. So you should really be putting the tableview all the way to the top of the screen (behind the nav controller). This property just makes sure that when the tableview is scrolled to the top it will have a big enough inset so that the navigation bar isn't hiding it.

Comment: Compare your first tableview with your second. Specifically the way the top is laid out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think, these arrays don't belong to the `MBViewController` from architectural point of view. I would separate them to a data layer (DataSource class of some sort, for instance) and keep a reference to the DataSource everywhere you need. Have a look at the [Second iOS App tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/SecondiOSAppTutorial.pdf) by Apple. It contains a simple example of data layer implementation.
**UPDATE:**
Also, check out Fogmeister's answer. He explains a possible implementation of such object rather well :)

As for why singleton didn't work as you expected in this case, I believe, the reason could be the following:
If you get to the `MBViewController` via a segue (which, I think, you are), then a new instance of `MBViewController` is created every time. If you access your arrays from MBViewController using self.myArray, then you access this new `MBViewController`'s `myArray`. While `sharedMBVC` keeps a reference to the shared instance, it's just ignored by the segue.

Answer (score 0):

in my ViewController.h

```
@property PTVData *ptvdata;
```

ViewController.m
ViewDidload

```
   ptvdata = [PTVData sharedPTVData];
    _sensorsCollection = ptvdata.sensorsCollection;
```

then i have a method in my ViewController.m

```
- (void) addSensorToCollection:( NSString *)sensorName{

  [[PTVData sharedPTVData] addSensorToCollection:sensorName];
    _sensorsCollection = ptvdata.sensorsCollection;

       [ self.tableView reloadData];


    }
}
```

My PTVData.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *sensorsCollection;
+(id)sharedPTVData;
-(id) init;
- (void) addSensorToCollection:( NSString *)sensorName;
@end
```

my PTVData.m

```
@synthesize sensorsCollection = _sensorsCollection;

+ (id)sharedPTVData {
    static PTVData *sharedPTVData  = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPTVData  = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedPTVData;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
           _sensorsCollection   = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"None", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) addSensorToCollection:( NSString *)sensorName{

    if (![_sensorsCollection containsObject:sensorName]&& sensorName!= nil) {
        [_sensorsCollection addObject:sensorName];

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of initializing your arrays in viewDidLoad, do it in sharedMBVC function. This will ensure that arrays are not re-initialized every time the view loads.

Comment: This is reasonable, but it doesn't answer the OP's question in any way. It should be a comment instead.